# mouse hover acts as click in qt application in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xorg, mouse, qt, events

Seems to be after a lid opening when i unplugged the DELL dock WD15 and closing the lid in the mean while (leaving my desk by example)  that mainly QT apps (not all apps such as Firefox/Terminal etc. by example) consider the mouse as clicked always, selecting or moving every object as it was clicked. Right click is changing the machine state as unclicked.
It seems that the release event is not received by QT event subsystem.

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 with xwayland or X. I have been trying to restart gnome-shell but no success. Logout/in solved the issue but i'd like to know where I should look into it or if there is tweaks I can do to isolate the issue.

Comment: After new investigation, it seems that the bug appears only with QT applications such as qmmp; vlc etc. But i discovered that the issue was not appearing wtih the flatpak version of VLC which is using a newer version (5.13.2). The current version 5.9.5 is having the issue. Any idea what I could restart to avoid a complete session reboot ?

Comment: with a small qt app displaying mouse event, I got a press event with only moving into the app. Then a normal click, gives a release event (no press) and then another click gives press/release then moving gives a press and so on ...

Comment: Here is a sample which helps to point out the issue

https://github.com/dabrain34/dev-toolkit/blob/master/misc/c/XEventTest/main.c

At least it would be nice to find a workaround without restarting the WM